# Common practices for modifying Python modules

Tags: python, module, reload

I have a Python Module test, I want to edit test and run some functions in test at the interpreter. Will Python automatically see the differences in the functions that I edit in test without reimporting? What is the appropriate word for this action?

1. What are the best practices for reimporting/reloading/redefining?
2. How can this be done efficiently? (It seems inefficient to highlight text with a mouse and then copy and paste).

**EDIT** Nothing mentioned so far is working so I will post a few more details:

A class is in my module, called Test. So I used the statement `from test import Test`. Now when I try the command `reload(test)` the interpreter tells me reload is undefined. If I do `import imp` then `imp.reload(test)` the interpreter tells me that `test` is undefined. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/437589)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're using Python 3, and all of the answerers are assuming you're using Python 2.

In Python 3, `reload` was moved from `builtins` to [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/imp.html#imp.reload).

So, the answer is:

```
imp.reload(test)
```

For future reference, if you're using Python 3, it's almost always worth mentioning it, unless you know for a fact that it's not relevant, because many of the old-timers (read: the people you want answer from) will assume 2.7.

Meanwhile, back to your main question:

> What are the best practices for reimporting/reloading/redefining?

For simple cases, `reload()` or `imp.reload()` are exactly what you want. (For *super*-simple cases, there's nothing wrong with copy and paste…)

But it's very easy to confuse yourself when you have, e.g., some object `bar` of class `foo.Bar` and then reload `foo`. It also doesn't play too well with `from foo import *`, which is often handy for interactive sessions.

If you can start up a new interpreter session and import the module, that's much cleaner. If you need a bunch of objects created to start playing with the module, you can temporarily add them as globals to the module, or create a wrapper module that defines them. Some IDEs can wrap all of this up so just hitting some accelerator key sequence causes it to restart the interpreter and rerun your `import` and all your setup stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> Will Python automatically see the differences in the functions that I edit in test without reimporting?

No.

> What is the appropriate word for this action?

See the builtin [reload(*module*)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload).

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, you should absolutely **not** have a module named `test` because Python already has one in its standard library.

`test` is undefined because you imported `Test`, not `test`.  You need to `import test` as well.

But note that due to the way `imp.reload()` works, reloading `test` *will not* update `Test`; that will still refer to the old copy of the class.  You'd have to `from test import Test` again, as well.

The full sequence of events:

```
>>> import imp
>>> import test
>>> from test import Test
>>> Test().whatever()
# edit your code
>>> imp.reload(test)
>>> from test import Test  # or: Test = test.Test
>>> Test().whatever()
```

The moral of this story is that `reload` sucks and you should avoid it at all costs.  If you want to re-run a bunch of code after every edit to a library, just put that code in a *file* and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there's a module named `data.py` that contains:

> ```
> def foo():pass
> ```

```
In [13]: import data

In [14]: dir(data)
Out[14]: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'foo']
```

Now add another function to data.py, while the shell is still running:

> ```
> def foo():pass
> def bar():pass
> ```

```
In [15]: import data

In [16]: dir(data)     #new function bar is not fetched by the import
                       #coz it simply loads the data object already present in memory

Out[16]: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'foo']
```

Use `imp.reload()` to reload the module object.

```
In [17]: import imp

In [18]: imp.reload(data)
Out[18]: <module 'data' from 'data.py'>

In [19]: dir(data)
Out[19]: 
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 'bar',
 'foo']          # bar fetched
```

`help()` on `reload()`:

> reload(module) -> module
>
> Reload the module.  The module must have been successfully imported
>   before.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus `from test import Test` is equivalent to `import test;Test=test.Test;del test`, so as there's no pre-loaded module in memory for `reload()` your code fails.